# How to open a link in chrome browser, even though the default computer browser is 'Safari'?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

I've built a chrome packaged app, and I'm trying to make one of the buttons in it open the chrome browser in a specific link.

For this, I used `window.open("http://myLink.com")`, which works, but unfortunately it opens the default browser rather than chrome. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only happens from inside the app window.

If you call `window.open` from the background page, it will open in Chrome.

So, send it to your background page:

```js
// app window
function openInChrome(url) {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "openURL", url: url});
}

// background
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if(message.action == "openURL") window.open(message.url);
});
```

Comment: while this trick does open the window in Chrome, it's unable to load the URL, I get the 'Aw, Snap!', 'Something went wrong while displaying this webpage. To continue, reload or go to another page.'. Event when I reload, I get the same message. But if I open another tab manually, and enter the same URL - it works. Any ideas?

Comment: After restarting the browser (completely) it works... really weird. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Actually, now, even though it works, I cannot send messages from the opened window to my chrome packaged app :( -- I use: window.chrome.runtime.sendMessage(chromeAppId, { action: action, content: content}); from the webapp, but the packaged app never gets it. If I open a new tab manually with the same URL, it does work. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like the opened window is like a sub-window of the background page, I don't have access to document.cookie from within that chrome tab, it's really weird. Is there another workaround to open a chrome tab from a packaged app?

Answer (score 2):

Use `chrome.browser.openTab`. See [issue](https://codereview.chromium.org/245933002). At the moment it's in dev channel.

Comment: Unfortunately I need a solution for the stable channel. Do you know any workaround?