# How to launch an external website from a chrome app?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I'm looking to link to a sign up page on an external webapp via a chrome app.  The simplest way to manage this seems to be to open a new tab in the chrome browser (not a new webview in a new window of the app).

[Tabs seem deprecated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) and a webview appears very unofficial and unsafe.  Basically, is there a way to effectively do this:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/signup">Sign up</a>
```

And the bigger question of course: is there a better way to approach what seems like a simple problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conceptions, *"Tabs seem deprecated and a webview appears very unofficial and unsafe"*, seem *very* strange. `tabs` is simply not enabled for Apps, and `<webview>` is alive and well.

But if you *must* open it in the browser, `window.open` will do the trick. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26918255/934239).

Edit: Also, [upcoming](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=358315) is the `chrome.browser.openTab` API. Leave your feedback if you have use cases for this feature.